# Batch-wise processing or image-by-image processing? (DINO V1)

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, training-data, self-supervised-learning

I've been trying to recreate the Dino V1 traning set up for a personal project. For which I've take majority of the code from this repo: [https://github.com/facebookresearch/dino[dinov1](https://github.com/facebookresearch/dino%5Bdinov1) link][1](https://github.com/facebookresearch/dino)

And rn I'm almost done with it except for one part in the main_dino.py file there is a function called train_one_epoch whereby in line 318 they have given:

`teacher_output= teacher (images[:2]) # only the 2 global views pass through the teacher`

Now I know how pytorch tensor indexing/slicing works. Hence, if images are a batch of images of a structure:

**(batch size, num crops, c, h, w)**

1. How would doing images[:2] get you the global crops of all the images in a given batch?
2. Are they processing images in batch here or is the "images" list here just a list containing multiple crops from a SINGLE input image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to the call of `train_one_epoch()` there was another modifiaction to the models, both the [`student` and `teacher` models are wrapped](https://github.com/facebookresearch/dino/blob/7c446df5b9f45747937fb0d72314eb9f7b66930a/main_dino.py#L182) with [`MultiCropWrapper`](https://github.com/facebookresearch/dino/blob/7c446df5b9f45747937fb0d72314eb9f7b66930a/utils.py#L594) class. Just take a look at the class' docstring as follows:

```py
class MultiCropWrapper(nn.Module):
    """
    Perform forward pass separately on each resolution input.
    The inputs corresponding to a single resolution are clubbed and single
    forward is run on the same resolution inputs. Hence we do several
    forward passes = number of different resolutions used. We then
    concatenate all the output features and run the head forward on these
    concatenated features.
    """
```

So this MultiCropWrapper class handles the forward passes, and it is also mentioned that it does several forward passes for different resolutions.